In my Blazor server side app, I want to blur the related razor page when a "loading" spinner is shown on the page. How can I do that?
In my Blazor server side app, I am using a "loading" spinner, when I run a method that takes few seconds time. This part is working as expected. But during the spinner is turning on the screen I want to blur the related razor page (The whole razor page except the spinner). How can I do this?
My code for the spinner is shown below:
Razor page:
  @if (Loading_spinner == true)
  {
     <div class="spinner"></div>
  }

CSS:
.spinner {
    border: 16px solid silver;
    border-top: 16px solid #337AB7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation: spin 700ms linear infinite;
    top: 40%;
    left: 55%;
    position: absolute;
}


One approach would be to create a reusable "loading component" you can use across your pages that shows a full-page blurred overlay when loading:
LoadingComponent.razor:
@if (IsLoading)
{
    <div class="blur-overlay"></div>
    <div class="spinner"></div>
}

@Loaded

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public required bool IsLoading { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public required RenderFragment Loaded { get; set; } = default!;
}

Your page:
@attribute [Route(PageRoutes.Index)]

<LoadingComponent IsLoading=@isLoading>
    <Loaded>
        
        <div>
            Here's some content!
        </div>

    </Loaded>
</LoadingComponent>

@code
{
    bool isLoading = true;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        isLoading = true;

        // Load something slow...

        isLoading = false;
    }
}

See this other question for how to achieve the full page blur: Full Page Blur in CSS
